# Complex Domain coloring vs Complex Range (over the output) coloring: which one brings more information?

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, visualization

Currently I am learning how to do [domain coloring visualizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring). Basically, as Wikipedia says:

> Domain coloring is a technique for visualizing functions of a complex
> variable ...There were many earlier uses of color to visualize complex
> functions, typically mapping argument (phase) to hue.

So basically I have learned how to do the basic hue map when we have a complex  injective function $f(z)$. These are some simple examples:

First row left-right: $(1)\ f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\ ,\ (2)\ f(z)=\frac{(z^2-1)(z-2-i)^2}{z^2+2+2i}\ ,\ (3)\ f(z)=z^3+1 $

Second row left-right: $(4)\ f(z)=z^5-1\ ,\ (5)\ f(z)=e^z$.

[image]

They are the mappings we are used to see. But to my surprise, then I tried a "reverse" mode, instead of mapping over the positions of the input complex points (the domain of the function), mapped the output points with the conversion to hue of the original input points, a kind of "Range coloring" or "Image coloring" or "coloring map over the result" of the function, the results were also very impressive. They are the other side of the coin of the relationship between the Domain and the Image/Range of the function:

[image]

Here is a zoom of the second example:

[image]

So my point is: I can understand that visualizing the Image/Range/output of the function in the position of the original points of the Domain as "hue/brightness/saturation" colors provides interesting information about the location of output of the function; but, why the Range or Image coloring is not as popular as the direct Domain coloring? or why are not they treated as complementary to each other?

> So the questions I would like to share are:
>
> 1. Why the Range/Image coloring is not so popular as the Domain coloring technique?
> 2. What type of complementary information can we find in the Range/Image coloring that we could not find or understand by visualizing a Domain coloring pattern?
> 3. Are there papers or documents regarding this kind of alternative visualization?

I think that in terms of complex domain coloring still there are things to explode and we are seeing only one side of the coin yet. And the other side seems quite interesting!

(If somebody wants a copy of the Python code used to make the examples, please let me know and I will add it to the question)

Comment: The inverse of an analytic function isn't in general analytic. Good luck to [represent multi-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm).

Comment: Not an answer, but an observation: **If** you think of an image as a map from a surface into a color space, then the "complex argument to RGB hue" mapping is a function $h:\mathbb C\to[0,1]^3$. Now given a function $f:\mathbb C_d\to\mathbb C_r$, the only way to compose $f$ and $h$ is to take $h\circ f:\mathbb C_d\to[0,1]^3$, which is the domain coloring method. *To the extent* that this is the preferred way to think about images, then domain coloring seems more natural.

Comment: @reuns I am aware of that "little" problem, but my question is focused on "which information can we obtain from a visualization based in the Range/Image" and not the Domain, independently of the inverse being analytic or not. Even not being analytic my question still remains valid: there will be some characteristics of the pattern that could provide information about the function that are not seen in the domain coloring version of the visualization.

Comment: @ChrisCulter good point, that explains neatly why the technique is focused on the Domain.

Comment: @reuns I can see your point, but... even if the function is bijective?

Comment: Define mathematically what you are plotting. $f(z)$ analytic is locally bijective around $z=a$ (so that $f^{-1}(w)$ is analytic around $w = f(a)$) iff $f'(a) \ne 0$.

Comment: @reuns This is what I see: a set $S$ of complex numbers $S=\{f(z)\}$ whose color values are a conversion of the original complex Domain $D\{z: z\in \Bbb C\}$. I am not interested in if that relation can be defined by an specific analytic function or not, just in the visualization of the points of the set in this "reverse" mode, and how that visualization might or not provide complementary information to the usual visualization. What I can understand from your comments is that the "reversed" visualization does not make sense if it cannot be defined as an analytic function.

Comment: ... Take a function $\phi : \mathbb{C} \to \text{RGB} = [0,1]^3$. In one case you are plotting $(x,y) \mapsto \phi(f(x+iy))$. In the other case you are plotting $(x,y) \mapsto \phi(f^{-1}(x+iy))$. Try with $f(z) = e^z$ to see why the fact $f^{-1}$ is not **globally** analytic means you'll have some problems to plot it in a [satisfying way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm). Locally (if $f'(a) \ne 0$) then $f^{-1}$ is just an analytic function, exactly as $f$.

Comment: @reuns thanks, I really appreciate your time and explanation. Lessons learned!

Comment: @iadvd Please can you send me the python script that you used to do the domain coloring.

Comment: @Yassir hi! sure, it is at my blog, check this link, cheers! http://hobbymaths.blogspot.com/2017/09/complex-domain-coloring-vs-complex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in order to be able to close the question, I am gathering the kind comments
made by Chris Culter and reuns. I think they give very valuable insights (written in the same time order they were written):

Credits to Chris Culter:

> Not an answer, but an observation: If you think of an image as a map from a surface into a color space, then the "complex argument to RGB hue" mapping is a function $h:\Bbb C \to {[0,1]}^3$. Now given a function $f:\Bbb C_d \to \Bbb C_r$, the only way to compose $f$ and $h$ is to take $h∘f:C_d \to {[0,1]}^3$, which is the domain coloring method. To the extent that this is the preferred way to think about images, then domain coloring seems more natural.

Credits to reuns:

> Take a function $\varphi: \Bbb C \to RGB={[0,1]}^3$. In one case you are plotting $(x,y) \to \varphi (f(x+iy))$. In the other case you are plotting $(x,y) \to \varphi(f−1(x+iy))$. Try with $f(z)=e^z$ to see why the fact $f^{−1}$ is not globally analytic means you'll have some problems to plot it in a satisfying way. Locally (if $f′(a)≠0$) then $f{−1}$ is just an analytic function, exactly as $f$.